# manually downloading maven-resources-plugin:2.5

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, m2eclipse

I am using Maven 2.2.0 and Eclipse Juno. I am trying to import one of the existing Maven project into workspace.

I got following error.

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

I thought to download that plugin "maven-resources-plugin" manually.

Can any one suggest how to download the plugin manually and avoid this error. I checked pom.xml( I have its dependency too).

Comment: Can you pastebin a longer error log?

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu. I have uploaded the complete error.

Comment: Can show the pom.xml file? Have you tried to compile and package the project on command line instead within Eclipse? Why are you using such an old version of Maven? If you are using Juno with the m2e plugin you are already using Maven 3 in Eclipse why not using on command line?

Comment: @khmarbaise. I have successfully compiled the project on command line. Build is success. But stil importing maven project is throwing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to download plugins manually. The plugin is present in the [central repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/), so Maven should be able to download it.

Did you disable the central repo? Are you behind a firewall that blocks access to some remote servers?

Or maybe you do have the plugin locally, but the file is corrupt.

Anyway, to install it, just download the [`pom`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom) and the [`jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.jar), and use the [maven-deploy-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) to [install the file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html#The_deploy%3adeploy-file_Mojo).

Comment: ..Thank you for the response. I have already a pom.xml for my project. Do I need to still download it. I have uploaded the complete log.

Comment: I have the plugin already. It seems it is corrupt."\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin\2.5". Shall I replace its content

Comment: Try to remove it, and then try again. If Maven does not find the plug-in, it tries to re-download it from the repository.

Comment: @User222 I'm not talking about the pom of your project, but the pom of the maven plugin. Like Zoltán said, if the plugin's pom or jar files are corrupt, just remove them and try to compile again.